# Yii:: File not Uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am trying to upload simple image file on Yii. But I not getting any url on my controller on submit.
Neither I am getting any thing on $_FILES nor in $_POST. Please check my following code I am sure I am making some small mistake some place.

**MODEL**

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('image_url', 'required'),
        array('image_url', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png','on'=>'import'),
        array('image_url', 'length', 'max'=>256),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('image_url', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

**CONTROLER**

```
public function actionImportVideo(){
     $model=new Image();
    print_r($_POST); 
    if(isset($_POST['image_url']))
    {
        print_r($_FILES);
        $model->attributes=$_POST['image_url'];
        $model->image_url=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image_url');
        if($model->save())
        {
            $model->image->saveAs('path/to/localFile');
            // redirect to success page
        }
    }
    $this->render('import_video', array('model'=>$model));

}
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="form">

<?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget(
            'CActiveForm',
            array(
                'id' => 'upload-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            )
        );
?>

        <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image_url', array('class' => 'col-md-3 control-label')); ?>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'image_url'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-actions">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('class' => 'btn red')); ?>
        </div>
<?php  $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

When I print $_POST in my controller I get

```
Array ( [Image] => Array ( [image_url] => ) [yt0] => Submit )
```

Please help. Thanks In Advance

Comment: What you get in `$_FILES` variable (your files are coming not via POST, but via FILES)?

Comment: O God. I am getting my input in FILES perfectly. I followed this example
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/. And it wasted my 30 odd mins. Thanks @Justinas

Comment: I think you did wrong here in rules
"array('image_url', 'length', 'max'=>256)"
just remove this and check.
Other wise go through this url once
http://www.saidur-rahman.com/how-to-upload-file-in-yii-framework/